# ValueError: can't find recovery API version in input target-files

Tags: android, python, android-source

I am trying to create a patch for different `AOSP` versions upgrading, without changing the APKs located in app or `priv-app` folders, which means the APPs version should hold still in the original versions.

I’ve checked the `OTA` Package Tools out on [AOSP website](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/tools.html#incremental-updates):
Right now, I have the AOSP source code in Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to implement the "incremental updates" with command shown as the website.

However, a `ValueError` message appears after I do that as the following:

```
unzipping target target-files...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 1119, in <module>
main(sys.argv[1:])
File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 1062, in main
OPTIONS.info_dict = common.LoadInfoDict(input_zip)
File "~/openlinux_kk-amlogic/build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 120, in LoadInfoDict
raise ValueError("can't find recovery API version in input target-files")
ValueError: can't find recovery API version in input target-files
```

Could anybody do me a favor to provide some methods possibly solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem I have successfully gotten the answer, I have to make my patch file with the zip file `target_files.zip`, not the general zip file, then the python is able to create the patch file.
However, I still have a problem that after I finish creating the patch file, and trying to flash it via adb sideload command, 
After finish flashing this procedure, the result after I flashing the zip didn’t work, and a message shown as the following:

> system/bin/filename” has unexpected contents

That filename stands for the file I tuned it in the patch file, as the figure shown:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vhLY.jpg]

If my method is wrong, does anybody know how to apply the patch I created with sideload flashing?
Thank you in advanced.